# While installing libx11-dev E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: apt, package-management

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. When I run `sudo apt install libx11-dev` I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libx11-dev : Depends: libx11-6 (= 2:1.6.4-3ubuntu0.1) but 2:1.6.4-3ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
              Depends: libxcb1-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libx11-doc but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try: `sudo apt update`, then try the install again.

Comment: @user535733 it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `aptitude`:

`sudo aptitude install <package-name>`

If you don't have `aptitude` installed on your machine `sudo apt-get install aptitude`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me!